# I am not being able to run this script in linux cluster with qsub

Tags: bash, shell, sh, qsub

I have written a script to run a program for some bioinformatics work however the program does not run when I try to run it as a bash for multiple samples below is the code and try to run it with qsub as that is how we can run code in our Debian cluster after doing qlogin. If anyone can let me know where I am getting wrong.

```
#!/bin/sh
#$ -S /bin/bash

SAILFISH_INDEX=/scratch/GT/genomes/Homo_sapiens/NCBI_spiked/GRCh38/Sequence/sailfishIndexes
floc=/data/GT/pgermain/wbs/rnaseq/raw/lieber.dec2013
OUT_DIR=/scratch/GT/benchmark/QT/sailfish

tf="\n%E elapsed,\n%U user,\n%S system, \n %P CPU, \n%M max-mem footprint in KB, \n%t avg-mem footprint in KB, \n%K Average total (data+stack+text) memory,\n%F major page faults, \n%I file system inputs by the process, \n%O file system outputs by the process, \n%r socket messages received, \n%s socket messages sent, \n%x status"

names="AJ81 
AJ82
AJ88
AJ89
AJ93
Sample_AJ83
Sample_AJ84
Sample_AJ86
Sample_AJ87
Sample_AJ90
Sample_AJ91
Sample_AJ92"

for s in $names; do
    echo "calling Sailfish quant on $s"
    /scratch/GT/softwares/time -f "$tf" LC_ALL=C sailfish quant -i $SAILFISH_INDEX -l "T=PE:O=><:S=U" -1 <(zcat $floc/$s/*R1*.fastq.gz) -2 <(zcat $floc/$s/*R2*.fastq.gz) -o $OUT_DIR/$s -p 8
    done
```

Comment: pasting the script in http://www.shellcheck.net/shows an error in the `../time` function. Cross check if it is the way it should be.

Comment: I want to capture the timeframe for the execution, how shall I do that if I do remove the time function

Comment: I am not discussing the logic, I just say that shellcheck shows basic errors and the script seems to have some in that line. Cross check that because it is quite helpful.

Comment: Yes I am saw the same thing in shellcheck.net where it is showing the below error _in sh, process substitution is not supported, even when sh is actually bash._. However this should not be the problem, the script runs if I run for indivdual samples , now I want to run for all the samples in the $floc and for each run I want the time constraints and the script fails in that., so am asking.

Comment: Why don't you use `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh`? Most problems can come from there.

Comment: no it does not work with `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84573/discussion-between-vchris-ngs-and-fedorqui).

Comment: Please clarify a bit your question: 1) do you want to run it qlogin (interactively) or with qsub (batch)?  2) What have you tried? In what conditions were you able to succeed? 3) What is the error you get?  4) your instruction is a one-line with some concatenation, are you able to split it so that it's easier to debug?

Comment: This problem is taken care of , there is a bug in the tool which does not allow it to run in this way, I had to do it individually and obtain the result. It is a problem of the glib and the different linux clusters and its organization.